# Calculate non-integer frequency with NumPy FFT

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I would like to calculate the frequency of a periodic time series using NumPy FFT. As an example, let's say my time series `y` is defined as follows:

```
import numpy as np
freq = 12.3
x = np.arange(10000)
y = np.cos(x * 2 * np.pi * freq / 10000)
```

If the frequency is an integer, I can calculate it using `np.argmax(np.abs(np.fft.fft(y)))`. However, in case the frequency is not an integer, how do I calculate the frequency with more precision?

EDIT: To clarify, we are not supposed to know how the time series `y` is generated. The above code snippet is just an artificial example of how a non-integer frequency could come up. Obviously if we already know the function that generates the time series, we don't need FFT to determine the frequency.

Comment: What is your definition of *the* frequency of a periodic time series?  Does your definition make sense for something like `10 + cos(2*pi*x) + 100*cos(3*2*pi*x)`?  Does `np.argmax(np.abs(np.fft.fft(y)))` work the way you expect for that example?

Comment: No, my definition doesn't work for your example. But that's beside the point. I just need to know how to use FFT with non-integer frequencies.

Comment: If your data really REALLY contains only one frequency then `N=count_of_zeros`, `T=interval_from_first_to_last_zero`, `freq=(N-1)/T`

Comment: The periodic time series doesn’t contain any non-integer frequencies. The sampled signal does. If you are interested in determining the frequency of the sampled cosine with better precision simply fit a parabola to the three samples around the max of the DFT.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your signal more resolution

```
import numpy as np
freq = 12.3
x = np.arange(100000)  # 10 times more resolution
y = np.cos(x * 2 * np.pi * freq / 10000)  # don't change this

print(np.argmax(np.abs(np.fft.fft(y))) / 10)  # divide by 10
# 12.3
```

The number of data points in `x` need to be 10 times more than the number you divide `y` with. You could get the same effect like this:

```
x = np.arange(10000)
y = np.cos(x * 2 * np.pi * freq / 1000)

print(np.argmax(np.abs(np.fft.fft(y))) / 10) 
# 12.3
```

If you want to find the frequency with two decimals the resolution needs to be 100 times more.

```
freq = 12.34
x = np.arange(10000)  
y = np.cos(x * 2 * np.pi * freq / 100)  # 100 times more resolution

print(np.argmax(np.abs(np.fft.fft(y))) / 100)  # divide by 100
# 12.34
```

Comment: We are not supposed to modify the inputs.

Comment: @cjo. Your question doesn't really make sense. Do you want a tutorial on fitting or interpolation? Machine learning perhaps?

Comment: @cjo. I think your issue is more on *how FFT works* rather than a matter of *how it's done in python or numpy*.

Comment: this is the correct approach ... when using Fourier Transform there is a basic relationship between frequency resolution and number of samples used ... so to get smaller increments between the frequency bins generated by your call to FFT then just supply more samples ... @cjo this is not modifying the input just using a wider window of samples of that input

Answer (score 1):

You can pad the data with zeros before computing the FFT.

For example, here's your original calculation.  It finds the Fourier coefficient with the maximum magnitude at frequency 12.0:

```
In [84]: freq = 12.3

In [85]: x = np.arange(10000)

In [86]: y = np.cos(x * 2 * np.pi * freq / 10000)

In [87]: f = np.fft.fft(y)

In [88]: k = np.argmax(np.abs(f))

In [89]: np.fft.fftfreq(len(f), d=1/10000)[k]
Out[89]: 12.0
```

Now recompute the Fourier transform, but pad the input to have a length of six times the original length (you can adjust that factor as needed).  With the padded signal the Fourier coefficient with maximum magnitude is associated with frequency 12.333:

```
In [90]: f = np.fft.fft(y, 6*len(y))

In [91]: k = np.argmax(np.abs(f))

In [92]: np.fft.fftfreq(len(f), d=1/10000)[k]
Out[92]: 12.333333333333332
```

---

Here's a plot that illustrates the effect of padding the signal.  The signal is not the same as above; I used different values with a much shorter signal to make it easier to see the effect.  The shapes of the lobes are not changed, but the number of points at which the frequency is sampled is increased.

[image: plot]

The plot is generated by the following script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fs = 10
T = 1.4
t = np.arange(T*fs)/fs

freq = 2.6
y = np.cos(2*np.pi*freq*t)

fy = np.fft.fft(y)
magfy = np.abs(fy)
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(fy), d=1/fs)
plt.plot(freqs, magfy, 'd', label='no padding')

for (factor, markersize) in [(2, 9), (16, 4)]:
    fy_padded = np.fft.fft(y, factor*len(y))
    magfy_padded = np.abs(fy_padded)
    freqs_padded = np.fft.fftfreq(len(fy_padded), d=1/fs)
    plt.plot(freqs_padded, magfy_padded, '.', label='padding factor %d' % factor,
             alpha=0.5, markersize=markersize)

plt.xlabel('Frequency')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude of Fourier Coefficient')
plt.grid()
plt.legend(framealpha=1, shadow=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: This doesn’t give any more resolution. It is equivalent to interpolating in the Fourier domain. You can determine the position of the peak with the same precision using this method or simply fitting a parabol to the tree samples around the max of the DFT.

Comment: @Cris, that's correct.  As I was writing the answer, I wondered how long it would take for someone to make that comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using either interpolation or zero-padding (which is equivalent to entire vector interpolation) to potentially improve your frequency estimation, if the S/N allows.  Sinc kernel interpolation is more accurate than parabolic interpolation.